# How to retrieve request date + timestamp in an Fn function

Tags: fn

is there a way to obtain the date and timestamp when the request is received by Fn server before triggering the mapped function?  It appears that `HTTPGatewayContext.getInvocationContext().getRequestHeaders()` contain an attribute `Fn-Deadline`, which seems to be request received (or start of function trigger) date and timestamp + timeout; I am hoping there is a simple way to obtain the date and timestamp when the request is received by Fn that I may have missed.

Comment: You might add some tags, I assume this refers to the Fn serverless project? What language relates to the question?

Comment: Yes, it is related to Fn serverless project.  I had added fn tag, is there another tag I should add?